# TCPDF Spotcolor specific for SVG

Tags: pdf, svg, tcpdf

I would like to put a specific color to a svg that i insert in a PDF thanks to TCPDF

this color will allow a printer to cut automatically
I know i would have to use spotcolors.

as here: https://tcpdf.org/examples/example_037/

the SetFillSpotColor function works perfectly for text or a rectangle
but when I use ImageSVG this has no effect

i add name CutContour directly in svg, example :

```
<path fill="CutContour" d="M271.44,849.229c-1.254,0.174-2.604,0.489-3,0.701...
```

but not works too.

example my code PHP:

```
$pdf->AddSpotColor('CutContour', 0, 0, 0, 100);
$pdf->ImageSVG(     $filename_svg ,             0,      0,      $largeurmm, $hauteurmm, 'CutContour',   false,      false,      0,          false);
```

I can't find a solution,
can you help me?

Comment: Instead of adding '[SOLVED]' to the question title, please accept the correct answer by clicking the tick at its upper left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you can't get away with using `cutcontour` as the spot color name, correct? The ImageSVG parser appears to force the color name to lowercase, which means it doesn't match against the `CutContour` name when it goes to look for it in the TCPDF instance's list of added spot colors.

If that guess is correct, try adding the color to the predefined list in the `TCPDF_COLORS` class (see spotcolor static property), either by editing `include/tcpdf_colors.php` or adding a line like this to your script.

```
TCPDF_COLORS::$spotcolor['cutcontour'] = array( 0, 0, 0, 100, 'CutContour');
$pdf->AddSpotColor('CutContour', 0, 0, 0, 100);
```

This way, when it goes to look for the lowercase name, it'll find a match and return the proper spot color array. (Note: Tested in TCPDF 6.2.17)

Comment: Thank you EPB, 
I confirm it works perfectly, you save my life.